# Why do I need to follow the OAuth spec/guidelines?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization, bearer-token

I feel silly even asking this question, but am at the limits of my understanding, and am hoping someone can provide some context.

I'm looking at the following (https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-for-java/) which states:

> The **access_token** is what will be used by the browser in subsequent requests... The **Authorization** header is a standard header. No custom headers are required to use OAuth2. Rather than the type being Basic, in this case the type is **Bearer**. The access token is included **directly after the Bearer keyword**.

I'm in the process of building a website, for which I'll be coding both the back-end REST service, as well as the front-end browser client. Given this context, why do I need to follow any of the guidelines given above? Instead of using the **access_token, Authorization and Bearer** keywords, what's stopping me from using any keywords I like, or skipping the **Bearer** keyword entirely in the header? After all, as long as the front-end and back-end services both read/write the data in a consistent manner, shouldn't everything work fine?

Are the keywords and guidelines given above merely best-practice suggestions, to help others better understand your code/service? Are they analogous to coding-styles? Or is there any functional impact in not following the above guidelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given this context, why do I need to follow any of the guidelines given above?

Because they are standardized specifications that everyone is meant to conform to if they want to interact with each other.

> Instead of using the **access_token, Authorization and Bearer** keywords, what's stopping me from using any keywords I like, or skipping the **Bearer** keyword entirely in the header?

Nothing, except that it won't be OAuth anymore.  It will be something custom that you created for yourself that noone else will understand how to use, unless you publish your own spec for it.

> After all, as long as the front-end and back-end services both read/write the data in a consistent manner, shouldn't everything work fine?

Who is to say that you alone will ever write the only front-end?  Or that the back-end will never move to another platform?  Don't limit yourself to making something custom when there are open standards for this kind of stuff.

> Are the keywords and guidelines given above merely best-practice suggestions, to help others better understand your code/service?

No.  They are required protocol elements that help the client and server talk to each other in a standardized manner.

[**Authorization**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.8) is a standard HTTP header used for authentication.  It has a *type* so the client can specify what kind of authentication scheme it is using (Basic vs NTLM vs Bearer, etc).  It is important for the client to specify the correct scheme being used, and for the server to handle only the schemes it recognizes.

**Bearer** is the *type* of authentication that OAuth uses in the `Authorization` header.  **access_token** is a *parameter* of OAuth's Bearer authentication.

If you use the `Authorization` header (which you should), you **must** specify a *type*, as required by RFCs [2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) and [2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617):

```
Authorization  = "Authorization" ":" credentials

credentials = auth-scheme #auth-param

auth-scheme    = token
auth-param     = token "=" ( token | quoted-string )
```

So, in this case, **Bearer** is the `auth-scheme` and **access_token** is an `auth-param`.

> Are they analogous to coding-styles?

No.

> Or is there any functional impact in not following the above guidelines?

Yes.  A client using your custom authentication system will not be able to authenticate on any server that follows the established specifications.  Your server will not be able to authenticate any client that does not use your custom authentication system.